# Chaining Rspec Custom Matchers

Tags: ruby, rspec

For testing reasons I've recently moved some of my RSpec matchers to use the class form rather than the DSL. Is there a way to easily get chaining behaviour when they are in this form.

E.g.

```
class BeInZone
  def initialize(expected)
    @expected = expected
  end
  def matches?(target)
    @target = target
    @target.current_zone.eql?(Zone.new(@expected))
  end
  def failure_message
    "expected #{@target.inspect} to be in Zone #{@expected}"
  end
  def negative_failure_message
    "expected #{@target.inspect} not to be in Zone #{@expected}"
  end
  # chain methods here
end
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of chained method call you'd like to be able to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new method with the name of chain, which normally should return `self`. Typically you save the provided chained state. Which you then update the `matches?` method to use. This state can also be used in the various output message methods too.

So for your example:

```
class BeInZone
  # Your code

  def matches?(target)
    @target = target

    matches_zone? && matches_name?
  end

  def with_name(name)
    @target_name = name
    self
  end

  private
  def matches_zone?
    @target.current_zone.eql?(Zone.new(@expected))
  end

  def matches_name?
    true unless @target_name

    @target =~ @target_name
  end
end
```

Then to use it: `expect(zoneA_1).to be_in_zone(zoneA).with_name('1')`

The reason this works is that you are building the object that you are passing to either the `should` or `expect(object).to` methods. These methods then call `matches?` on the provided object.

So it's no different than other ruby code like `puts "hi there".reverse.upcase.gsub('T', '7')`. here the string `"hi there"` is your matcher and the chained methods are called on it, passing the final object returned from `gsub` to `puts`.

The built-in expect [`change`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/change.rb) matcher is a good example to review.